# Spring Security. Different view for the same page for different roles, possible?

Tags: java, security, spring-security, web, roles

For example, we have Book List page.

This Page contains list of books.

If user role = "ADMIN" show on Page button "Remove Book" or something like "Edit Book".

If user role = "SIMPLY_USER" user can not see any buttons likes "Remove.." or "Edit...".

After quick look on Spring Security 3 - I cant find any implementation for my case.

It is true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the spring security taglib in your jsp to decide what to display according to the user role.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">

This content will only be visible to users who have
the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```

Reference : http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html